# Kill Tomcat on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, terminal, cmd.exe

I am trying to deploy a JavaEE application, but I get this error:

> Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.

The reason is obvious, the solution, not so much.

According to [this website](https://indikapra.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/starting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8084-is-already-in-use/), it should be easy as well. However, when I ran `netstat -o`. This is what I get on port 8084:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8084         www:49887              TIME_WAIT       0
```

Tried to restart the computer, error persisted. How am I supposed to `taskkill` this?

Comment: Normally I would expect that another instance of your application server was running.  I've had several instances where I accidentally loaded up two server instances and one was still using 8084.   Of course the PID wasn't 0.  That threw me.  Typically PID 0 is the scheduler however that also may depend on the OS.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83322/which-process-has-pid-0

What OS are you running exactly and what version?

Comment: @Dale I am using `windows 8.1` (updated the question to reflect this). I still didn't figure it out, as whenever I restart it is still there and with the same `PID = 0`. I will try to run highjackthis and see if I can find something weird.

Comment: You may want to try to kill the process by name.  in Windows when an application has a PID of 0 it simply indicates that its idle.  This might not be give you a proper handle on the process you wish to kill as it really isn't its PID but more of a status.  Here are some other ways to kill a process without using the PID.  Note one of them is killing the process by name.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/4-ways-to-kill-a-process-kill-killall-pkill-xkill/

Comment: `TIME_WAIT` is (the residue of) a previous connection that has been closed, and shows pid 0 because it is no longer open by any process. To look for the *listening* (open) socket, add `-a` to `netstat` and filter for `LISTENING` e.g. with `findstr`; also `-n` is faster. Alternatively since the miscreant came back after reboot, look in Services, or other autostarts using `msconfig` or similar, for something webserverish configured to autostart. Incidentally that webpage is hopelessly confused; `-o` is wrong for Unix, although `-a -n` are good for both Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 0):

CMD:

`task kill /f /Im 00.exe`

Note: switch 00.exe with the process name (you can see it with:

`tasklist`

Shows a list of processes